# **TemplateSyntaxError at /shop/** Could not parse the remainder: '[1:]' from 'product[1:]

Tags: css, django, error-handling

The following link is the gist link of my index.html

https://gist.github.com/MahdinOhi/b083179a8261b1d89291b69f6d66d5c8

This was my code of index.html I am getting this error for this code: TemplateSyntaxError at /shop/ Could not parse the remainder: '[1:]' from 'product[1:] And also My carousel's card is not in a proper way (I think it's the fault of CSS) Here is the error I am getting (In Jpg):

[image]

I want to fetch the product names and images from the database.
I need to troubleshoot the error. I want to make better my CSS.

Comment: Share the template, you don't share the location of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with

```
{% for i in product[1:] %}
  .....
{% endfor %}
```

`product[1:]` this is not directly supported within django templates. Instead you can try [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)

```
{% for i in product|slice:"1:" %}

  ... Rest of your template codes

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: how to fetch  products from databases